# Should the router drive SPA application state?

Tags: vue.js, url-routing, single-page-application, vue-router, vuex

This is an architectural question about keeping the state of my SPA application in sync with the url. I'm using vue, vue-router, and vuex. Here is a reoccurring problem in my application, that i'm going to describe at a very high level.

Let's say a user clicks a link that takes him from `/customers` to `/customers/JohnSmith`. My app then mutates the store. The state has now been updated because the user clicked a button, and not because the route changed.

In other words.

1. User clicks link
2. State is updated because click. (Because i clicked on a component that was associated with an object, i have direct access to the customer object)
3. Route is changed

However, if i refresh the page on `/customers/JohnSmith`, step 1 is no longer applicable, and my store is in an invalid state. Additionally, if i use the browser back button to go from `/customers/BobbyHill` to `/customers/JohnSmith`, my app still displays data about BobbyHill, even though the url is JohnSmith.

Does that then mean, my application state should always derive from the URL?

1. User clicks link
2. Route is changed
3. State is updated because route changed (Based on the url, find a customer object within my store with the same name)

The above steps will handle all 3 cases where a user clicks button to go to `/customers/JohnSmith`, refreshes, or goes forward/backward in history. So no matter how a user arrives on a page, the page should show the correct data.

Is this the correct way of handling this problem?

Comment: In my opinion it's more convenient to mutate state based on route, and use navigation guards before entering private routes in order to check identities.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to mutate the store when navigating to an different route. Is that to load the customer's details from the backend server ?